# How do I properly downscale an image from 300 dpi down to 72 dpi using imagemagick?

Tags: windows, imagemagick, image-processing, image-manipulation

As the title says, I want to know the proper way to downscale my image that is originally 300 dpi down to 72 dpi while still maintaining the same quality of the image.

By quality, I don't mean the resolution because I'm expecting the resolution to go down, but I meant like sometimes imagemagick compresses the image in the process too which introduces artifacts

I'm using imagemagick on Windows if that matters.

Comment: If Image Magick is reducing the quality of the images its likely changing the jpg compression ratio.  Try playing with the compression percentage with the switch -quality XX%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPI is parameter which is get in charge when you print the image. There is no relation between image dimensions (in electronic form) and DPI. If you want to change the DPI this can be done w/o any change in image itself (this is meta information). If you want to downscale the image (for example from 4000x3000 to 2000x1500 pixels) you will always loose quality. Also when we talk about JPEG where is another parameter, related to compression which can decrease additionally the quality.

With imagemagick you can change DPI by command:

```
convert input.jpg -density 72 output.jpg
```

To scale down the image you can use command

```
convert input.jpg -scale 24% -density 72 output.jpg
```

Comment: I'm sorry I did not make myself clearly, what I meant is that for example, in my art program, if I have an A4 size file with 300dpi settings, the pixel count is 2480x3508 but if I set the dpi for the same A4 size to 72dpi, the pixel count becomes 595x842. That is what I'm looking for. I want to get the 72dpi version of any image (not just A4, it was just for example) where it downscales

Comment: @user9564371, see my edited answer

Comment: hello, where did you get the 24% value? @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @user9564371 `72/300 in percentage` Also `595/2480*100 ~24`